# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when adding row in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, indexoutofboundsexception

```
this.tModel = new AdvancedMibTableModel(); 
this.table = new JTable(this.tModel);
this.tModel.addRow(new Object[]{"sysLocation","1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6","0",""});
```

when running the above code the following exception occured.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.justifyRows(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.insertRow(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.addRow(Unknown Source)
```

what i am doing wrong here? what is the actual problem?
can anyone suggest a solution?
i tried both addRow() and insertRow() but the same problem occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exceptions is pretty clear

[at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29)

v.s.

[this.tModel.addRow(new Object[]{"sysLocation","1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6","0",""});](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

- have to create `Vector<Object>` instead of new `Object[]`
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the columns to Model?

If not, you should to avoid this exception.

You can add columns to model as follows:

```
TableColumn location = new TableColumn();
// ...
// set location fileds i.e. header etc.
// ...
this.tModel.addColumn(location);
```

Comment: the colomns are added in the customised model "AdvancedMibTableModel"

Comment: the model is already set with 4 colomns. in the above code i want to set that model to the table and want to add rows in it. but cant add beacause of this exception